# How to force a div to use css style?

Tags: html, css, razor, blazor

I have multiple component in a razor file and those components bases I cannot modify. The components does not have 'style' and 'css' properties.
One of them generates a div with the following structure

```
<div class="pr-6 pl-3 py-4 ">
    <div class="flex space-x-4">
    </div>
</div>
```

I should apply a `width: 100%;` on the div like a `style` or a `class` that has the style.

I tried to add new css class in the xy.razor.css file, but I cannot find the div and cannot apply the styles.

I tried (and some other very basic stuff):

```
::deep div.pr-6.pl-3.py-4 {}
.pr-6.pl-3.py-4 {}
```

I am not a css wizard myself. Is there any way to solve this?

p.s.: Finding the DOM element with JS and apply the class on the element is not a way :D

Comment: You can use `!important` after the style like 
`p{color: red !important; }`  But please note that It will force the element to have this style and you will not be able to overwrite it. :D

Comment: @DevRudra I know the !important, but i cannot refer to the specific div. And that is the problem.

Comment: It's not very clear what your issue is - why didn't the classes you tried work (is it because you missed the dash on py4)?  Is that html the div you are trying to target?

Comment: Sorry for the typo, I missed the '-' on on the question, but not in my file

Comment: So is this a typo problem and your problem is solved?

Comment: Of course it's not a type problem, i'd never post something like that

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to add this to the page, from which you call the component:

```
<style>
    .pr-6.pl-3.py-4 {
        width: 100%!important;
    } 
</style>
```

This however will apply to all `<div>` tags with `class="pr-6 pl-3 py-4"` on your page. If you have multiple of these and it should only apply to one, you would possibley need to create an interim component, to isolate the one you need this for.